# Multiple imputation for missing data

Tags: data-imputation

I'm using multiple imputation in my mediation analysis and was wondering if the variables that I use for the imputation have to precede the study variables? For example if my mediator is self-esteem at age 10, do the variables use to develop missing values have to come from self-esteem scores before age 10 (I have self-esteem scores at age 12 & 14).

Thanks.